# SQL server query groupby

Tags: sql-server

This is the current table status and what i need is below.
Could anyone guide me with this SQL server query.

Here is my data as [original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYeph.png)

Thanks to @EdwardRusu here is the same data as text. Current Data:

```
+ -- + ---- + ---- + -------- + -- + -------- + -------- + ------- +
| ID | Date | Time | Category | N  | Response | CUST_ART | ADV_ART |
+ -- + ---- + ---- + -------- + -- + -------- + -------- + ------- +
| 1  | #### | #### | 1        | 1  | Null     | Null     | Null    |
| 1  | #### | #### | 2        | 2  | 45       | 45       | Null    |
| 1  | #### | #### | 1        | 3  | 25       | Null     | 25      |
| 1  | #### | #### | 2        | 4  | 13       | 13       | Null    |
| 1  | #### | #### | 1        | 5  | 20       | Null     | 20      |
| 1  | #### | #### | 2        | 6  | 2        | 2        | Null    |
| 1  | #### | #### | 2        | 7  | 53       | Null     | 53      |
| 1  | #### | #### | 1        | 8  | 41       | Null     | 41      |
| 1  | #### | #### | 2        | 9  | 28       | 28       | Null    |
| 1  | #### | #### | 1        | 10 | 66       | Null     | 66      |
| 1  | #### | #### | 2        | 11 | 36       | 36       | Null    |
| 1  | #### | #### | 1        | 12 | 66       | Null     | 66      |
| 1  | #### | #### | 1        | 13 | 125      | 125      | Null    |
| 1  | #### | #### | 1        | 14 | 127      | 127      | Null    |
+ -- + ---- + ---- + -------- + -- + -------- + -------- + ------- +
```

Desired Data:

```
+ -- + ---- + ---- + -------- + -- + -------- + -------- + ------- +
| ID | Date | Time | Category | N  | Response | CUST_ART | ADV_ART |
+ -- + ---- + ---- + -------- + -- + -------- + -------- + ------- +
| 1  | #### | #### | 1        | 1  | Null     | Null     | Null    |
| 1  | #### | #### | 2        | 2  | 45       | 45       | Null    |
| 1  | #### | #### | 1        | 3  | 25       | Null     | 25      |
| 1  | #### | #### | 2        | 4  | 13       | 13       | Null    |
| 1  | #### | #### | 1        | 5  | 20       | Null     | 20      |
| 1  | #### | #### | 2        | 6  | 2        | 2        | Null    |
| 1  | #### | #### | 2        | 7  | 53       | Null     | 94      |  <-changed ADV_ART column
| 1  | #### | #### | 1        | 8  | 41       | Null     | Null    |
| 1  | #### | #### | 2        | 9  | 28       | 28       | Null    |
| 1  | #### | #### | 1        | 10 | 66       | Null     | 66      |
| 1  | #### | #### | 2        | 11 | 36       | 36       | Null    |
| 1  | #### | #### | 1        | 12 | 66       | Null     | 66      |
| 1  | #### | #### | 1        | 13 | 125      | 252      | Null    |  <-changed CUST_ART column
| 1  | #### | #### | 1        | 14 | 127      | Null     | Null    |
+ -- + ---- + ---- + -------- + -- + -------- + -------- + ------- +
```

Editor's Note: As the comments state below, please edit your posting to include actual explanation of what you want to happen. In fact, I'm only including this note here because SO wouldn't let me save the edit because the code/explanation ratio was so terrible.

Comment: How does 53 become 94 and 125 become 252? What are the rules? What do the columns mean/represent?

Comment: if category = 1, then ADV_ART = ResponseTime; if category = 2 CUST_ART = ResponseTime. IF there are 2 or more consecutive 1 in category ADV_ART = sum of ResponseTime and Null of below rows.

Comment: Posting your data in your question is MUCH better than a picture. I will edit your question so we can at least see your info without leaving the question page.

Comment: Sadly your image has so much white space in it that posting it in your question is pretty useless too. :(

Comment: You should consider posting ddl (create table script) and sample data as inserts. That way we have something to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Use these UPDATE statements:

```
update [yourtablename]
set adv_art = 94
where category=2 and n=7 response=53 and adv_art=53

update [yourtablename]
set cust_art = 252
where category=1 and n=13 response=125 and cust_art=125
```

Comment: I like your sassy answer :)

Comment: From the data it looks like `n` alone is a unique key (and probably even primary key). If so, the queries might be simplified accordingly